# abstract method in class

Tags: java, oop, abstract

**A class automatically becomes abstract class when any of its method declared as abstract.**

I take this point in some blog. Can someone explain me Why entire class becomes abstract when we use only one abstract method.?

Comment: Your title implies something that doesn't exist. If you have an abstract method, the class has to be declared abstract (which means using the `abstract` keyword before `class`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it can't be instantiated directly anymore. Also, it's then a compiler error if you don't mark the class itself as `abstract`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm going to guess that the blog you mentioned was actually discussing C++. In Java, it's a compiler error to declare an abstract method within a class that is declared with the abstract keyword. With that said, Consider this (erroneous) code:

```
class A
{
    abstract void foo();
}

A a = new A();
a.foo(); //Whoa! what are we supposed to do??!
```

If `A` had been declared as abstract (as would be required in real code), it would have been impossible to instantiate it.

If any part of a class is missing (that is, it is declared abstract), the class must be abstract because *parts of it cannot be used*.

In C++, there is no `abstract` keyword-- a class is automatically abstract if it has any abstract methods (referred to as pure virtual functions in C++).

In Java on the other hand, a class is only abstract if it is declared with the `abstract` keyword. However, this keyword is required if there are any abstract methods, so the only difference between the two systems in practice is that Java allows abstract classes to not have any abstract methods. In both languages, a class must be abstract if it has any abstract methods: in C++, this is simply how abstract classes are defined, and in Java it is required via the mechanics of the `abstract` keyword.

Comment: I found the phrase in a "javarevisited" blog: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/abstraction-in-java.html.  So they **thought** they were discussing Java.  I guess this just points out the danger of relying on blogs--not all of them are trustworthy.

Comment: @ajb What phrase? That blog post seems to get the differences between concrete and abstract classes.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The one in boldface at the top of OP's post.  And yes, I think the blog post understands the difference, but that one piece of information is dubious.  (And a couple of the comments did point out the error.)

Answer (score 0):

Once a method is abstract, it is declared to have no implementation.  How would you suggest the VM instantiate an instance of that class?

Answer (score 0):

An abstract method is one that defines a contract for a method but does not implement the functionality.

To instantiate a class with methods that cannot meet the contract defined as there is no implementation wouldn't work. Thus an abstract method means that you should not be able to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 0):

> **A class automatically becomes abstract class when any of its method declared as abstract.**
>
> Can someone explain me Why entire class becomes abstract when we use
>   only one abstract method.?

The class has to be declared Abstract because the compiler expects a body for a normal class's method otherwise it will throw error. So either you write the method's body or declare the class Abstract

Example:

```
class SomeClass{

 // Method without body
 public void SomeMethod();

 public static void main(String[] args) {


    }   
}
```

When you try to compile it, you will get:

```
SomeClass.java:4: missing method body, or declare abstract
 public void SomeMethod();
```